# Java - Class Not Found exception

Tags: java, serialization, io

I am working on a project (this IS homework) where our professor gave us a .ser file and a Course.java file (Which is the class that he used to create the .ser file)  My issue is that when I try to load the data from the .ser file into an array I get a ClassNotFoundException.

what I ended up doing was creating a new class in my project named exactly the same as the class my professor created and copying/pasting his code into that class.  I did do some research and my the .class files are in the same project folder and I am able to use the methods from the Course class in my project.

After some guess and check work I know that the ClassNotFoundException gets kicked back at line 16,

test = readData();

My Code:

```
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
    import java.io.Serializable;



    public class ObjectSort
     {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
     Course[] test = new Course[24];

    test = readData();

} // end main()

// read data from class binary file and put into an array of courses
public static Course[] readData() throws Exception
{
    // create class object to hold data from file
    Course[] holder = null;

    // create file and object input streams
    FileInputStream holderFile = null;
    ObjectInputStream holderObject = null;

    // catch exceptions
    try
    {
        // set up file and stream objects
        holderFile = new FileInputStream("fall2014.ser");
        holderObject = new ObjectInputStream(holderFile);

        // read the object from a file
        holder = (Course[]) holderObject.readObject();

    }
    catch (IOException exc)
    {
        exc.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
      holderObject.close();
    }

    return holder;
} // end readData()

}// end class ObjectSort
```

Proffesor's class code:

```
   import java.io.*;


   class Course implements Serializable {


private String campus;  // the campus on which the course is offered
private String course;  // the course number, such as CSCI 111
private String section; // the section number
private String crn;     // the CRN for this section
private int credits;    // the number od credits for the course
private String time;    // the time the course is offered, such as 8:00 to 10:00 A.M.
private String days;    // the Days the course is offered, suhc as MW


// constructors
Course() {
}

Course(String course, String section, String crn, int credits) {
    this.course = course;
    this.section = section;
    this.crn = crn;
    this.credits = credits;
}   // end Course() initalizing

// muatator methods

public void setCampus(String cmp) {
    this.campus = cmp;
}// end setCampus()

public void setCourse(String crse) {
    this.course = crse;
}// end setCourse()

public void setSection(String sect) {
    this.section = sect;
}   // end setSection()

public void setCRN(String crn) {
    this.crn  = crn;
}   // end setCRN()

public void setCredits(int cr) {
    this.credits = cr;
}   // end setCredits()

public void setTime(String tm) {
    this.time = tm;
}// end setTime()

public void setDays(String days) {
    this.days = days;
}// end setDays()


// accessor methods

public String getCampus() {
    return campus;
}   // end getCampus()

public String getCourse() {
    return course;
}   // end Course()

public String getSection() {
    return section;
}   // end getSection()

public String getCRN() {
    return crn;
}   // end getCRN()

public int getCredits() {
    return credits;
}   // end getCredits()

public String getTime() {
    return time;
}   // end getTime()

public String getDays() {
    return days;
}   // end getDays()


// method to compare by CRN using the String class compareTo()
public int compareTo(Course other) {
    return this.crn.compareTo(other.getCRN());
}   // end compareTO()

// method to return properties as a string
public String toString() {

    return    campus + " "
            + course + " "
            + section + " "
            + crn + " "
            + credits + " "
            + time + " "
            + days;

}    // end toString()

// You will need to add a method to return properties as a CSV string on one line
public String toCSVString()
{
    String record = campus + ","
            + course + ","
            + section + ","
            + crn + ","
            + credits + ","
            + time + ","
            + days + "\n";

    return record;
}  // end toCSVString()

}// end class Course
```

Error Stack:

```
  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: writecoursefile.Course
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ObjectInputStream.java:623)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1610)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1515)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1661)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1342)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
at ObjectSort.readData(ObjectSort.java:38)
at ObjectSort.main(ObjectSort.java:16)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)

    Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By copy/pasting your code into a test project, I get no error while running it...

Your exception probably comes from the package declaration, that should be writecoursefile for the Course class that your professor gave you.

Comment: wow fast reply! but could you explain a little more on what you mean (I am still fairly new to java) I ended up creating a new project named writecoursefile to change the package name and after copying and pasting I got a InvalidClassException...so it is headway :D (I could probably take it from here and research that exception, but I would like to know what it is that you are exactly talking about)

Comment: Actually, what IDE are you using ? Using Eclipse for instance usually lead you to underlining these annoying errors, and Bob's your uncle :-). But the package declaration is a kind of "folder" in which you declare your class. If another class calls it, you should either prefix the class name by its package name, or import the right class with its full name (i.e : import writecoursefile.Course;)

Comment: I am actually using two differente IDE's NetBeans (which is the required IDE for the course) and IntelliJ.  I use one and when I want to make a change or test something im not sure about I use the other.  gotta love dual monitors!

Comment: I am marking your answer as correct, I ended up deleting my entire project (with my code copied to a txt doc of course :P) and when I made the new project I kept in mind what you said about packages and it all complied/ran so thanks!